# Using the robot class in an if statement

Tags: java, accessibility, awtrobot

Hi im creating a game accessibility app which will take mouse input and convert it to arrow key press. I have a window split up into 4 sections and it prints out which sector the mouse is in now what i would like to do is take one of these

```
        if((e.getX() > O && e.getX() < X1) && (e.getY() > O && e.getY() < Y1)) {
            statusBar.setText("Up");
        }
```

and instead of

```
         statusBar.setText("Up");
```

it does

```
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress('W');
        r.keyRelease('W');
```

Any advice?

Comment: What is the question, rather problem ?

Comment: I cant get the robot to work